# Problems when using IIS7 and WCF - can't even load the .SVC

Tags: wcf, configuration, iis-7, windows-7, impersonation

I have developed a very simple WCF using  v2.0.50727 framework service that returns a string - a typical HelloWorld() scenario. However, the configuration is an absolute pain, and I really don't understand what I am doing wrong. Note I am an administrator on my machine using Windows 7.

So step by step, here is what I am doing:

1. Created a new website pointing to my WCF directory. The directory contains a .svc, a Web.config and a bin directory with the .dll and .pdb in it
2. Try and browse to the site:

   > Config Error - Cannot read configuration file due to insufficient permissions

   Therefore, I give the IIS_IUSRS account access to the directory.
3. Another error:

   > You do not have permission to view this directory or page because of the access control list (ACL) configuration or encryption settings for this resource on the Web server.

   Therefore, I ensure the user permissions are propagating down - which they are. The same problem comes up and and again - so time to try something different.
4. I look at the AppPools and they are using a newly created one for me using 4.0 integrated mode. I change it to `DefaultAppPool`

   > You do not have permission to view this directory or page because of the access control list (ACL) configuration or encryption settings for this resource on the Web server.
5. I turn on ASP.NET Impersonation - to pass through my user instead of the default

   > An ASP.NET setting has been detected that does not apply in Integrated managed pipeline mode.

   I change the pipeline to `Classic ASP.NET Pool` (which turned off ASP.NET security)

   > You do not have permission to view this directory or page because of the access control list (ACL) configuration or encryption settings for this resource on the Web server.
6. Turned ASP.NET Impersonation

   > You do not have permission to view this directory or page because of the access control list (ACL) configuration or encryption settings for this resource on the Web server.

--

Please can someone guide me as to what I'm going wrong? IIS 6 would just let me in straight away and I'm doing a significant amount of configuration just to load a .svc

Regards,

Dominic

Comment: Because .NET 3.0 uses the v2.0.50727 CLR and you have the choice of either that or .NET 4.

Comment: OK, you're on .NET CLR v2 - what version of the .NET framework are you using?? At times it appears you're talking about .NET 4 features....

Comment: .NET 3.5 compilation mode. I'm configuring on IIS7 which assumes I'm .NET 4.0ing it, which I'm not. I've also tried adding specific handlers for *.svc for .NET 2.0 aspnet_isapi.dll but that isn't working either.

Comment: What happens when you publish the web service by using the "Publish" command on the Project menu? Publish generally configures IIS the "right way"

Comment: "You do not have permission to view this directory or page because of the access control list (ACL) configuration or encryption settings for this resource on the Web server." . Weirdly, this .svc file is being served by the StaticFileHandler? That can't be good?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to add handlers for .svc. That happens when you install .NET.

The problem is not handlers; it's security. ASPNET impersonation seems like a red herring.  This is for a WCF service, right?  Maybe you're barking up the wrong tree.

You said you ensured that rights were "propagating down" - but check that.  For example, when you move a file from one dir to another, the file can carry an ACL that is not the "inherited" ACL you would expect if you just create the file in the folder originally.

Things to check:

- IIS_IUSRS  must have read+execute permissions on the physical directory
- The bin sub-directory needs to have proper permissions for IIS_IUSRS.
- the DLL in the bin subdir needs to be readable
- you probably want "anonymous" access enabled for the vdir.
- you need a web.config file, with the proper perms (but you'd get a different error if this was the problem)
- the .svc file needs to have the proper permissions

One step toward getting a .svc to work is to get a simple .htm page to load.  Does that work?  Once you get that, then load a simple .ASPX page, with code from the bin directory.  Once you get that, you should be able to get the .svc to run, no problem.

At that point you just need to do the WCF-specific configuration.